# how to solve : TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mahif.png)

i can not solve ....
how to solve : TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: here is my code... def save(self):
        print('Inventory saving')
        with open('Inventory.txt','w') as f:
            json.dump(self.pets,f)
        print('saved')
    def loads(self):
        print('inventory lading')
        if not os.path.exists('Inventory.txt'):
            print('skipping, nothing to load')
            return
        with open('Inventory.txt','r') as f:
            self.pets = json.loads(f)
        print('loaded...!!')

Comment: Try reading the data into a variable first, then passing that to loads

Comment: Pls put your code in answer as it's not readable here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using `loads` when you need `load`.  `json.load` is for file-like objects, and `json.loads` is for strings.  (You could also load the string into memory and then parse it with `json.load`, but you don't want to do that).

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add that you are not reading the file in the code, which leads to the following (example):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    print(file)
```

Output:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Use `read()`:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

Output:

```
word
```